# UITableViewCell ImageView becomes pixelated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a standard UITableViewCell (not custom), and I'm trying to use its cell.imageview property. I'm passing in images that are 44x44 pixels in dimension, and I am trying to scale down both the UIImageView and the UIImage. The result that I get is a smaller image that's pixelated. Why is that happening?

Also, is there a way to make the UIImageView within the UITableViewCell smaller? It's currently covering up the separator lines.

```
CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
[cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image]

Comment: Is it blurry on retina only?

Comment: @KiwiBastard i've only tried it on the retina

Comment: Pretty sure iOS is upscaling from 20x20 to 40x40 for retina, and that is why it's blurry. Can you supply the images as png's instead of in code? Eg resize the actual pngs to 20x20 and 40x40 @2x.

Comment: @KiwiBastard this seems to help, although it doesn't really seem super crisp. What size should I make my images if I want them to fit into the UIImageView inside the UITableViewCell for a retina device? Is 20x20,40x40@2x right? Also, do you have any idea why the separator lines are being cut off like that? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: The separator lines aren't cut off -- that's the new design.

Answer (score 1):

provide the correct double size images for retina displays, if you image is 44X44 for non retina, provide the @2x image in 88x88.

for the seperator: i assume you use storyboard: select the tableview in your storyboard. in the attribut inspector select "custom" for seperator insets( 3rd block) and set the values for left and right to 0. now you seperator will not be cutted :-)

Comment: You're right about the images, although the OP is trying to get them to show at 20x20, therefore the @2x images should be 40x40.
+1 for the storyboard adjustment of the separator line - this is the way that Apple intend them to look, but you can now adjust it from the left and right ends from within "IB".